# SQL Primary Key Constraint

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, primary-key

[image]

In a book I am reading they stated that in the teaches table, based on the Schema diagram in the picture above, the underlined column names are `Primary keys (ID, course_id, sec_id, semester, and year)`. I am a little confused on how that is possible since I originally thought that you can only have one `Primary Key` in a table. I don't really understand which are Primary Keys and which are foreign key constraints in the diagram above. Can someone please explain to me how to identify these keys through a diagram like this?

Furthermore is it possible to make `(course_id, sec_id, semester, and year)` `(foreigns keys)` from the section table that reference to teaches primary keys `(course_id, sec_id, semester, and year)`. That wouldn't work correct? Since for every combination of `(course_id, sec_id, semester, and year)` from section you may have multiple ID's from the teaches table since you can have multiple teachers for each section. So that would mean you have the foreign key from sections referencing multiple rows from teaches and that does not form a correct primary key combination for teaches.

Comment: They are primary keys in other tables; in teaches, they are references to primary keys in other tables, and should have a foreign key constraint --- that is, you should not be able to assign a course_id to a teaches that does not exist in the course_id table.  You can identify them by the column names and by the lines that are drawn from the field to the table / field that it is referencing.

Comment: So that means in section table the PK are course_id, sec_id, semester, and year. In other words, every combination of (course_id, sec_id, semester, and year) in section has to be unique correct? Since you cannot have duplicate values for a PK?

Comment: A table can only have one primary key.  Primary = 1.  A primary key is the KEY to getting what you want from a table :)  So in that section table, it will reference exactly one row in the course_id table, etc etc

Comment: On 2nd glance I don't think there's a PK in section, it appears to be a 'bridge' table to associate various keys from other tables.  FWIW, that diagram is pretty poor.

Comment: Yeah it is quite hard to follow what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only set 1 primary key for a table, BUT: A primary key consists of 1 or more columns.

The other point is:
In a diagram like the one above, you can identify the referenced column by simply following the arrow.
Example:
advisor.i_id references instructor.ID

Hope this helps!

Greetings

Comment: In such a diagram, you can identify the columns which are part of the primary key by the underscore. So for teaches, the primary key consists of all columns. Classroom f.e., the primary key is only building and room_no, capacity is not part of the pk.

Comment: Oh arite. So in section sec_id, semester, year, and course_id are the primary keys?

Comment: In section, sec_id, semester, year and course_id are the primary key (note the singular!), the primary key consists of these 4 columns. At the same time, the column course_id is the primary key for the table course AND one foreign key for the table section. A pk consisting of multiple cols can contain foreign keys in it as well.

Comment: Ohh I see now! Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: I had one more urging question haha. Since in the section table `(sec_id, semester, year and course_id)` are the primary key does that mean each row in the section table has to have a unique combination of `(sec_id, semester, year and course_id)`? So you can have like `(1234, fall, 2009, 15)` and `(1234, fall, 2009, 16)`. So basically for each row in the section table every column value has to be different when compared to the other rows.

Comment: "...each row in the section table has to have a unique combination of (sec_id, semester, year and course_id)..." Exactly, yes! And - to complete your example - you can also have "(1234, fall, 2010, 16)" and so on. The uniqueness of the pk (the combination of the pk columns values) is the point.